# Connect to SQL Server from Linux via JDBC using integratedSecurity (Windows authentication)?

Tags: java, sql, linux, sql-server-2008, jdbc

Hey I am having trouble connecting to an SQL Server with Java code that is running on Linux.

If I set `integratedSecurity=true`, then the java code fails with the following error:

```
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:b030b480-453d-4007-8151-a552150f74cd
```

which makes sense as there will be no `sqljdbc.dll` file on Linux.

But if I set `integratedSecurity=false`, then I get the following error:

```
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'IT_DEV_USER'.
```

So does anyone know how I can connect to SQL Server with `integratedSecurity` set to false? (Note that I cant even connect when the Java code is running on Windows when `integratedSecurity` is set to false.)

If not, is there any way I can get `integratedSecurity` working on Linux?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use integrated security and using JDBC Driver 4.0 or greater then you add the following in your jdbc connection string.

```
integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
```

More information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2015/01/09/jdbc-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication.aspx

Comment: Have you successfully done this? I am getting a Unable to obtain Principal Name for authentication error...

Comment: Try to specify the instance name, it should fix it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx

Comment: As far as I know, just adding that kerberos needs to be used is not sufficient: you need to have kerberos configured correctly, and you need to have a kerberos ticket from the AD.

Comment: Yes, the configuration for kerberos if required is to be done. Please check the link in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos` works for me in Linux, but make sure to remove `integratedSecurity=true` since you are not using Windows.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15:  "If you specify authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos but do not also specify integratedSecurity=true, the driver will ignore the authenticationScheme connection property and it will expect to find user name and password credentials in the connection string."

Answer (score -3):

You can't use integratedSecurity feature from Linux system, as it tied to windows system and uses your windows authentication. However, if you enable both SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode on your SQL Server, then you can create a login, map to corresponding database and use it in java from Linux.

To enable SQL Server authentication:

1. Right click on your server in management studio
2. Properties
3. Security
4. Server authentication -> SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode

Comment: Hey, I tried this and it still does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: You should be able to use the kerberos authentication built in to the SQL Server JDBC driver.

Answer (score -3):

If you dont want Integrated Security connection, then set that parameter to false and instead provide user and password in the connURL as below:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:port;databaseName=DB_NAME;integratedSecurity=false;user=login_user;password=login_pwd;";
```