# Migrating from jTDS JDBC driver to Microsoft JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds, mssql-jdbc

Microsoft has recently released a new JDBC driver (version 6.0.7507.100) with some very interesting features. I am mostly interested in the TVP feature. This is why I would like to replace the current jTDS driver with the Microsoft driver.

The problem arises when trying to log in to our production server. Lets say we use the domain user "mydomain\dbuser" to login to the sql server instance. This is the jtds jdbc url we have used so far:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:/sqlServer:1433/myDb;domain=mydomain;user=dbuser;password=secretPwd
```

It works like a charm.

But when I try to use the Microsoft driver, my application cannot establish a connection to the database. I tried the following URL strings:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://sqlServer:1433;database=myDb;username=dbuser;password=secretPwd
jdbc:sqlserver://sqlServer:1433;database=myDb;username=mydomain\dbuser;password=secretPwd
jdbc:sqlserver://sqlServer:1433;database=myDb;username=dbuser@mydomain;password=secretPwd
```

and many other permutations but with no success. The app fails with the following exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'mydomain\dbuser'
```

in the SQL Server log we get the following error:

```
Login failed for user 'mydomain\dbuser'. Reason: Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication. [CLIENT: 10.10.10.10]
```

Note that the application is supposed to run under Linux.

Does anybody know how the Microsoft JDBC URL should look like when connecting as a domain user?

Comment: I would recommend not passing credentials in the URL that way.  Pass them to the driver manager when you create the connection.

Comment: I will. As soon as I figure out how to make the login work

Comment: Moving it out of the URL WILL make it work.  You should be doing it using the DriverManager.

Comment: Tried with this: Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://sqlServer:1433;database=myDb", "mydomain\\dbuser", "secretPwd");
Did not work. Fails in the same way. Sorry for the formatting.

Comment: Username does not look correct to me.  Should be "dbuser".  Can you try that?

Comment: Tried with:Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"‌​); Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://sqlServer:1433‌​;database=myDb", "dbuser", "secretPwd"); I get the exception com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'dbuser'. Before it was com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'mydomain\dbuser'

Comment: Perhaps try adding `;integratedSecurity=true` to the end of your connection string, omit the userid and password from the `getConnection` call, and use [runas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.11).aspx) to launch your Java application?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the application is supposed to run on Linux,

Comment: Is SQL Server configured for "mixed authentication"? If so you need to pass the SQL Server username, not the Windows username. You can't use Windows authentication from Linux if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Apparently, with Microsoft's JDBC driver it was simply impossible to use `integratedSecurity=true` from Linux prior to version 4.0 of that driver because a whole bunch of magic happened in `sqljdbc_auth.dll`, which was a native Windows DLL. Version 4.0 introduced `authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos` so Java could do the magic. So apparently it *can* be done, but it takes quite a bit of configuration. More details [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/01/09/jdbc-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to SQL Server from Linux via JDBC using integratedSecurity (Windows authentication)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914061/connect-to-sql-server-from-linux-via-jdbc-using-integratedsecurity-windows-auth)

Answer (score 3):

My research in this issue has led me to the following conclusions:

- The simple transition from the jTDS driver to the Microsoft driver is not possible as I intended in the question. This is because the the jTDS driver implements NTLM authentication which is not available on the Microsoft driver.
- An alternative is to use the JavaKerberos authentication scheme (as Gord Thomson suggested) which is available on Linux machines. Fortunately, we have the Kerberos infrastructure set up in our production environment.

I have successfuly managed to add Kerberos authentication in my service mainly with the help of these Microsoft (blog) posts:

- [JDBC - This driver is- not-configured for integrated
  authentication](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/01/09/jdbc-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication/)
- [Using Kerberos Integrated Authentication to
  Connect to SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122(v=sql.110).aspx)

so I'll be using that.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Microsoft is currently developing a JDBC driver that supports NTLM.
You can follow a discussion that includes a preview here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/696

I tested the driver and it works, using the following connection string:

> jdbc:sqlserver://sqlServer:1433;databaseName=mydb;useCursorsAlways=true;IntegratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=NTLM;domain=domain;user=dbuser;password=xxxxx

I contacted Microsoft and now wait for a GA release date.

Answer (score 0):

**Not directly the answer to your question**, but if you want to fetch the latest driver (which might resolve your issue):

Microsoft latest release is https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774
which also has the *sqljdbc_xa* and *sqljdbc_auth* dlls for integrated security

From maven you would get https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/

Directly from source https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases

see notice: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc#download-the-dlls