# KafkaConnect - SQL Trusted Authentication (Windows)

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Currently to connect to a MSSQSL database I have to create a local SQL login as per login details below:

```
name=jdbcIbLog
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
**connection.user=username**
**connection.password=password**
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://servername
topic.prefix=webiblog
query=SELECT * FROM IB_WEBLOG_DUMMY_small
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
poll.interval.ms=5000
table.poll.interval.ms=5000
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=ID
```

This was a quick fix as I currently connect using windows authentication to MSSQL. Does Kafka-Connect support login with windows credentials?
This runs off of a Centos box

Expected output is to be able to provide username and password for a given Windows User which will allow the MSSQL connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure it's not going to work with [integrated authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017#Connectingintegrated) from CentOS as it relies on a `dll` (`sqljdbc_auth.dll`). 
However you should be able to use [Kerberos with your JDBC connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). See also [Connect to SQL Server from Linux via JDBC using integratedSecurity (Windows authentication)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914061/connect-to-sql-server-from-linux-via-jdbc-using-integratedsecurity-windows-auth).