# Unable to connect to SQL Server via JDBC on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, jdbc

I am able to connect to my SQL Server instance via the following JDBC connection on a **Windows** machine:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://<my_server>;databaseName=<my_db>;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;username=<my_user>;password=<my_pwd>
```

However, when the same connection string is invoked on a **Linux** machine, I get the following error stack:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host <my_server>, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection timed out: no further information.. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

I have tried altering the JDBC string to remove the `integratedSecurity=true`, according to this [forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914061/connect-to-sql-server-from-linux-via-jdbc-using-integratedsecurity-windows-auth), but I am encountering the same error message.

Is the error message related to authentication or networking?
I am able to SSH into the Linux machine and successfully ping `<my_server>`

Comment: Start with the minimal URL: jdbc:sqlserver://<my_server>;databaseName=<my_db>.  You assume that port is the default 3306.  There's a Connection method that lets you enter username and password as method parameters in addition to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try if I can reach 'my_server' on the standard port from your Linux client, e.g.

```
    telnet my_server 1433
```

as MS Sql Server is listening on port 1433, MySQL is listening on 3306.
If this is fine, use the basic URL as duffymo mentioned above. Probably add username and password:
         jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:1433;databaseName=my_db;user=my_user;password=my_password